# Is there a more efficient way to do one time conversions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The goal of the program is to determine if the coordinates a user inputs is closer to X or Y.

We use the class for the calculations:

```
class GeoPoint():
    def __init__(self, lat = 0, lon = 0, description = 'TBD'):
        self.__lat = lat
        self.__lon = lon
        self.__description = description
        
    def set_point(self, coords):
        self.__lat = coords[0]
        self.__lon = coords[1]
    
    def get_point(self):
        return self.__lat, self.__lon
    
    def set_description(self, description):
        self.__description = description
        
    def get_description(self):
        return self.__description
    
    def distance_calculation(self, coords):
        self.__lat = float(self.__lat)
        self.__lat = radians(self.__lat)
        self.__lon = float(self.__lon)
        self.__lon = radians(self.__lon)
        # [float(x) for x in coords] 
        # [radians(r) for r in coords]
        a = sin((self.__lat-coords[0]) / 2)**2 + cos(self.__lat) * cos(coords[0]) * sin((self.__lon-coords[1]) / 2)**2
        c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))
        distance_difference = c * 3958.8
        self.__lat = degrees(self.__lat)
        self.__lon = degrees(self.__lon)
        return distance_difference
    
    Point = property(get_point, set_point)
    Description = property(get_description, set_description)
```

And we get the input using:

```
 USER = GeoPoint()
    # Ask the user for their location. Create a third point to represent the user’s location.
    USER.Point = input("Enter coordinates: ").split(", ")
    USER.Point = [float(f) for f in USER.Point]
    USER.Point = [radians(r) for r in USER.Point]
    
    if X.distance_calculation(USER.Point) <= Y.distance_calculation(USER.Point):
        print(f"You are closet to {X.Description} which is at {X.Point}")
    else:
        print(f"You are closet to {Y.Description} which is at {Y.Point}")
```

Is there a better way to get the conversions for `def distance_calculations(self, coords)`?

It looks really inefficient to have to use conversions in two different places to only be used one time and then have to convert back to original information so it can be read in the `print()`

Comment: You're doing a lot of *unnecessary* conversions that are immediately overwritten. The `Point` property is not storing both `float` and `radians` versions of the lat/long coordinates. You set the coordinates to floats, then *replace* them with radians. Store the lat/long as floats, and let the distance method compute necessary angles from them.

Comment: Really, `Point` should be its own class, either a superclass of `GeoPoint` or the type of a single `point` attribute in `GeoPoint`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify this greatly. There's no need for the unnecessary getters and setters, and you should just store the lat/long coordinates as floats initially. Maybe something like

```
class Point:
    lat: float
    long: float

    def __init__(self, *, lat: float, long: float, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.lat = lat
        self.long = long

    def distance_from(self, other: 'Point'):
        # Use self.lat, self.long, other.lat, and other.long
        # to compute the distance between them.


    @property
    def point(self):
        return (self.lat, self.long)



class GeoPoint(Point):
    def __init__(self, *, description: str = 'TBD', **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.description = description

X = GeoPoint(...)
Y = GeoPoint(...)
lat, long = input("Enter coordinates: ").split(", ")
USER = GeoPoint(lat=float(lat), long=float(long))

closer = min([X, Y], key=USER.distance_from)

print(f"You are closer to {closer.description} which is at {closer.point}")
```

Comment: Yours is much better thank you! Only issue I'm getting:
`NameError: name 'Point' is not defined`

Comment: Inside the class being defined, the eventual class name needs to be provided as a string. Will update.